# how to handle individual increase decrease option in a table in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a page where I can handle the quantity of any product. but how can I use increase or decrease function for individual products?

```
     <tbody>
             {
               newProducts.map(newProduct => {
                  return(
                         <tr key={newProduct._id}>
                             <td>{newProduct.name}</td>
                             <td>{count}</td>
                             <td><FontAwesomeIcon onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)} icon={faPlus}></FontAwesomeIcon></td>
                             <td><FontAwesomeIcon onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)} icon={faMinus}></FontAwesomeIcon></td>
                             <td> <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={() => handleDelete(newProduct._id)} icon={faRemove}></FontAwesomeIcon></td>
                          </tr>
                         )
                   })
            }
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Create a separated `<Product />` component that has its own state and use it in the loop.